# How can you find the OpenGraph url for fb:comments?

Tags: rest, facebook-opengraph, facebook-comments

We've inherited an app that uses

```
<fb:comments href="/article/101" width="500" num_posts="20"></fb:comments>
```

And the comments work similar to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Couto/w8xcf/ in that a full url is not specified.

However now they want to get a total of comments for that article for use elsewhere on the site.  If it was using the full url as http://domain.com/article/101 we could use an OpenGraph query easily:

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://example.com/

https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://example.com/

```
https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.facebook.com%2Ffql%3Fq%3Dselect%20post_fbid%2C%20fromid%2C%20object_id%2C%20text%2C%20time%20from%20comment%20where%20object_id%20in%20(select%20comments_fbid%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url%20%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F')%26pretty%3D1>
```

(sorry, couldnt figure out how to link the above url..)

Anyone know of a way to retrieve the ID facebook is using when someone doesnt specify an href (like the fiddle) or only a relative path?  Obviously we could update the fb:comment code to use a full url but we'd lose all the comments for each article... hoping there is a way to avoid that

Comment: Facebook probably turns that relative url into an absolute url by adding the domain in front of it. Not sure if www. makes a difference either.

Comment: Thanks for www tip, did not think about that, sadly no dice.  Also tried with and without http(s)